# Android how to open Index activity always

Tags: android, android-activity

Today got problem that my apps cannot go Index activity always whenever I've already configured in manifest file.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.ppshein.inm.IndexActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Problem is, I have two activities (index and detail).

1) open my apps, it go Index activity.
2) Click button in Index activity, then go Detail activity.
3) Click android "Home" button to exit in Detail activity.
(not click on android "back" button).

4) Once again open my apps, it automatically go to Detail activity (that's I don't want).

When I want is whenever I open my apps, always want to go Index activity first even close at Detail activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, I've found the answer. The right answer is to add following attribute into the activity we want to set default as always.

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```